# Lui en vouloir pour / de son insouciance

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Je lui en veux d'être insouciant. (1)
>
> Je lui en veux pour son insouciance. (2)

La première phrase est correcte. Est-ce que *lui en vouloir **pour** + nom* est correct aussi ou il faut dire *lui en vouloir **de** + nom* ?

Je trouve très peu d'exemples contenant *en vouloir **pour** + nom* sur Google, mis à part *en vouloir pour preuve* qui est une expression.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux variantes sont correctes, avec la différence que celle avec ***de*** est beaucoup plus utilisée que celle avec ***pour***, comme nous le montre [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je%20lui%20en%20veux%20pour%2C%20je%20lui%20en%20veux%20de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20lui%20en%20veux%20pour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20lui%20en%20veux%20de%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

En fait on peut dire

> Je lui en veux ***de/pour*** + ***verbe/substantif***:

Par exemple:

> - Je lui en veux ***d’être*** celle qu’elle est. Je lui en veux ***pour sa façon*** de rire... En réalité, je lui en veux ***de l’aimer*** autant.([source](https://short-edition.com/fr/oeuvre/tres-tres-court/je-lui-en-veux))
> - Je lui en veux ***pour avoir transformé*** un de mes amis. ([source](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Revue_des_Deux_Mondes_-_1879_-_tome_34.djvu/761))
> - Est-ce que peut-être je lui en veux ***de sa mort***? ([source](http://aircrigeweb.free.fr/ressources/negationnisme/diversAltouCerisy.html))

Je dois dire que j'ai eu du mal à trouver des exemples avec "de + substantif", "pour + substantif" est plus fréquent. Cet autre [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en%20veux%20pour%20%C3%A7a%2C%20en%20veux%20de%20%C3%A7a%2C%20en%20veux%20pour%20avoir%2Cen%20veux%20d%27avoir&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20veux%20pour%20%C3%A7a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20veux%20pour%20avoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20veux%20d%27%20avoir%3B%2Cc0) n'a pas trouvé d'exemples avec "je lui en veux de ça", tandis qu'il y en a pas mal avec ***je lui en veut pour ça***. ***Je lui en veux d'avoir*** est beaucoup plus fréquent que ***je lui en veux pour avoir***.

La fréquence d'usage des expressions peut vous servir de critère, mais n'hésitez pas à faire votre choix d'après ce qui vous semble plus approprié dans votre contexte aussi. Personnellement, je pense que

> Je lui en veux pour son insouciance.

marche très bien!

("Remercier" est un autre verbe qui accepte "de" aussi bien que "pour".)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, moi aussi, j'ai trouvé peu d'exemples avec "de + substantif", même avec "pour + substantif" ne sont pas si nombreux... J'ai l'impression qu'il est "plus correct" d'écrire "Je lui en veux **de** + verbe" et "Je lui en veux **pour** + substantif.

Comment: Oui, je suis arrivée à la même conclusion après avoir étudié la question un peu. Merci de m' en avoir donné l'occasion!

Comment: Il en va de même pour "remercier" : _Je vous remercie de + verbe_ et _Je vous remercie pour/de + substantif_.  [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1012)

Comment: Merci pour le link. Je connaissais pas.

Comment: "BDL" est très utile.